# Questions in android app gets repeated when shuffling them

Tags: arrays, repeat, shuffle

I am new to the whole coding world. And I am currently creating a learning app for kids, and one of the categories included is taking a quiz. I wanted to shuffle all the questions and I was able to do so but the problem I am facing now is that the questions gets repeated

here is the code i used for Quiz questions activity

```
public class QuizQuestions extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button back;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView toolText;
    private ImageView img;
    private TextView mScoreView;
    private TextView mQuestionView;
    private TextView mButtonChoice1;
    private TextView mButtonChoice2;
    private TextView mButtonChoice3;
    private TextView mButtonChoice4;
    private String mAnswer;
    private int mScore = 0;
    private int mQuestionNumber = 0;
    private Button nextQues;
    private ImageView dialogImg;
    private TextView dialogText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_questions);

        //Assign action bar
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //assign TextView in Toolbar
        toolText = findViewById(R.id.toolbar3_text);
        //setText of TextView in Toolbar
        toolText.setText("Quiz");

        //Assign back button
        back = findViewById(R.id.back);

        //setOnClickListener for back btn
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //onClick for back button
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(QuizQuestions.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }//end of onClick
        });//end of setOnClickListener

        mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quiz_question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option_one);
        mButtonChoice2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option_two);
        mButtonChoice3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option_three);
        mButtonChoice4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option_four);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quiz_img);

        updateQuestion();


        mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                }if (mQuestionNumber > 9) {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(QuizQuestions.this, Results.class);
                    newIntent.putExtra("FINALSCORE", mScore);
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizQuestions.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.questions_dialog, null);

                    mBuilder.setView(mView);

                    dialogImg = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image);
                    dialogText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    nextQues = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.next_question);


                    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

                    if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
                        dialogText.setText("Well Done!!");

                    } else {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                        dialogText.setText("Oops, you missed that!!");
                    }


                    nextQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            {

                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }

        });

        mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                }

                if (mQuestionNumber > 9) {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(QuizQuestions.this, Results.class);
                    newIntent.putExtra("FINALSCORE", mScore);
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizQuestions.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.questions_dialog, null);

                    mBuilder.setView(mView);

                    dialogImg = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image);
                    dialogText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    nextQues = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.next_question);


                    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

                    if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
                        dialogText.setText("Well Done!!");

                    } else {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                        dialogText.setText("Oops, you missed that!!");
                    }


                    nextQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            {

                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }

        });

        mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                }
                if (mQuestionNumber > 9) {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(QuizQuestions.this, Results.class);
                    newIntent.putExtra("FINALSCORE", mScore);
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizQuestions.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.questions_dialog, null);

                    mBuilder.setView(mView);

                    dialogImg = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image);
                    dialogText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    nextQues = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.next_question);


                    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

                    if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
                        dialogText.setText("Well Done!!");

                    } else {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                        dialogText.setText("Oops, you missed that!!");
                    }


                    nextQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            {

                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }

        });

        mButtonChoice4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mButtonChoice4.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                }
                if (mQuestionNumber > 9) {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(QuizQuestions.this, Results.class);
                    newIntent.putExtra("FINALSCORE", mScore);
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizQuestions.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.questions_dialog, null);

                    mBuilder.setView(mView);

                    dialogImg = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image);
                    dialogText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    nextQues = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.next_question);


                    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

                    if (mButtonChoice4.getText() == mAnswer) {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
                        dialogText.setText("Well Done!!");

                    } else {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                        dialogText.setText("Oops, you missed that!!");
                    }


                    nextQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            {

                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }

        });

        }



    private void updateQuestion(){
        shuffleQuestions();
        mQuestionView.setText(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getQuestion());
        mButtonChoice1.setText(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getOptionOne());
        mButtonChoice2.setText(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getOptionTwo());
        mButtonChoice3.setText(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getOptionThree());
        mButtonChoice4.setText(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getOptionFour());
        img.setImageResource(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getImage());

        mAnswer = questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getCorrectAnswer();
        mQuestionNumber++;

    }

    Question q01 = new Question("Which animal is considered the only flying mammal?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Flying Squirrel","Penguin","Bat","None of the above", "Bat");
    Question q02 = new Question("Which animal lay its eggs in the water?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Lion","Giraffe","Elephant","Frog", "Frog");
    Question q03 = new Question("Which animal have very long neck?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Beer","Giraffe","Leopard","Elephant", "Giraffe");
    Question q04 = new Question("How does Frogs catch their food?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Mouth","Hands","Tongue","None of the above", "Tongue");
    Question q05 = new Question("Where did Pandas originate from?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Egypt","Australia","South Korea","China", "China");
    Question q06 = new Question("What does Rhinoceros eat?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Meat","Plants","Meat and Plants","None of the above", "Plants");
    Question q07 = new Question("How does a Kangaroo move around?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Walking","Jumping","Running","All of the above", "Jumping");
    Question q08 = new Question("Within how long can baby Goats stand and take their first steps?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Minutes","Days","Weeks","Months", "Minutes");
    Question q09 = new Question("Do male Gorillas often have the same body size of the females?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Yes, they do","No, females often have bigger body","No, males often have bigger bodies","All of the above", "No, males often have bigger bodies");
    Question q10 = new Question("DE_R is missing one letter. What is it?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "A","E","I","R", "E");
    Question q11 = new Question("What happens when giant stars explode at the end of their lifecycle?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Small stars are formed","Disappears","Forms a Black Hole","None of the above", "Forms a Black Hole");
    Question q12 = new Question("How long does it take for sun light to reach the earth?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "2 minutes","6 minutes","8 minutes","10 minutes", "8 minutes");
    Question q13 = new Question("What is the name of the fourth planet from the sun?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Earth","Mars","Jupiter","Saturn", "Mars");
    Question q14 = new Question("How do dolphins breathe?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Through their nose","Through their blow hole","Using their gills","None of the above", "Through their blow hole");
    Question q15 = new Question("What is the name of the following fruit?", R.drawable.pomegranate_big_pic, "Pear","Pineapple","Pomegranate","Pumpkin", "Pomegranate");
    Question q16 = new Question("What is the name of the following animal?", R.drawable.lion_big_pic, "Tiger","Leopard","Snake","Lion", "Lion");
    Question q17 = new Question("What is the correct spelling of the following animal?", R.drawable.kangaroo_big_pic, "Kangaroo","Kangroo","Kangeroo","Kangaro", "Kangaroo");
    Question q18 = new Question("What is the world's largest land animal?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Whale","Elephant","Snake","Bear", "Elephant");
    Question q19 = new Question("What is the name of the following animal?", R.drawable.zebra_big_pic, "Horse","Donkey","Zebra","None of the above", "Zebra");
    Question q20 = new Question("What is the correct spelling of the following animal?", R.drawable.rhino_big_pic, "Rhinoseros","Rhinocros","Rhinoceros","Rhinosers", "Rhinoceros");
    Question q21 = new Question("What Panda's mostly eat?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Meat","Fish","Plants","Bamboo", "Bamboo");
    Question q22 = new Question("How many planets are there our solar system?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "9","7","8","6", "8");
    Question q23 = new Question("How many moons does Mercury have", R.drawable.ques_mark, "2","None","1","3", "None");
    Question q24 = new Question("What is the fourth largest planet in our solar system?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Venus","Uranus","Neptune","Saturn", "Neptune");
    Question q25 = new Question("What is the farthest planet from the sun?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Jupiter","Neptune","Mercury","Saturn", "Neptune");
    Question q26 = new Question("Cantaloupes are good source of which vitamins?", R.drawable.cantaloupe_big_pic, "Vitamins A & B","Vitamins A & C","Vitamins B & C","Vitamins E & C", "Vitamins A & C");
    Question q27 = new Question("What is the name of the following fruit?", R.drawable.tangerine_big_pic, "Orange","Lemon","Peach","Tangerine", "Tangerine");
    Question q28 = new Question("How many limbs does and octopus has?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "7","10","8","6", "8");
    Question q29 = new Question("Where were onions first cultivated?", R.drawable.redonion_big_pic, "Japan","South Korea","China","Vietnam", "China");
    Question q30 = new Question("What is the correct spelling of the following animal?", R.drawable.squirrel_big_pic, "Squirel","Squirrel","Squirl","Squerril", "Squirrel");

    Question [] questionArray = new Question[]{
            q01, q02, q03, q04, q05, q06, q07, q08, q09, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, q19, q20, q21, q22, q23, q24, q25, q26, q27, q28, q29, q30
    };


    private void updateScore(int point) {
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);
    }

    public void shuffleQuestions(){
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(questionArray));
    }

}
```

I also created the following Questions.class:

```
public class Question {

    private String question;
    private int image;
    private String optionOne, optionTwo, optionThree, optionFour;
    private String correctAnswer;

    public Question(String question, int image, String optionOne, String optionTwo, String optionThree, String optionFour, String correctAnswer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.image = image;
        this.optionOne = optionOne;
        this.optionTwo = optionTwo;
        this.optionThree = optionThree;
        this.optionFour = optionFour;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }


    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getOptionOne() {
        return optionOne;
    }

    public String getOptionTwo() {
        return optionTwo;
    }

    public String getOptionThree() {
        return optionThree;
    }

    public String getOptionFour() {
        return optionFour;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer() {
        return correctAnswer;
    }
}
```

Please accept my apologies if the code is messed up, like I said, I am new to all of this, and self taught. So any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're calling the shuffle function in *updateQuestion*. So it updates the *questionArray* everytime *updateQuestion* method is called.

Solution

Remove *shuffleQuestions();* from *updateQuestion* method and add it before *updateQuestion();* in onCreate method such that shuffling happens once in the beginning when the class is loaded.

Updated source code

```
public class QuizQuestions extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button back;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView toolText;
    private ImageView img;
    private TextView mScoreView;
    private TextView mQuestionView;
    private TextView mButtonChoice1;
    private TextView mButtonChoice2;
    private TextView mButtonChoice3;
    private TextView mButtonChoice4;
    private String mAnswer;
    private int mScore = 0;
    private int mQuestionNumber = 0;
    private Button nextQues;
    private ImageView dialogImg;
    private TextView dialogText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_questions);

        //Assign action bar
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //assign TextView in Toolbar
        toolText = findViewById(R.id.toolbar3_text);
        //setText of TextView in Toolbar
        toolText.setText("Quiz");

        //Assign back button
        back = findViewById(R.id.back);

        //setOnClickListener for back btn
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //onClick for back button
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(QuizQuestions.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }//end of onClick
        });//end of setOnClickListener

        mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quiz_question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option_one);
        mButtonChoice2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option_two);
        mButtonChoice3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option_three);
        mButtonChoice4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option_four);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quiz_img);

        shuffleQuestions();
        updateQuestion();


        mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                }if (mQuestionNumber > 9) {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(QuizQuestions.this, Results.class);
                    newIntent.putExtra("FINALSCORE", mScore);
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizQuestions.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.questions_dialog, null);

                    mBuilder.setView(mView);

                    dialogImg = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image);
                    dialogText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    nextQues = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.next_question);


                    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

                    if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
                        dialogText.setText("Well Done!!");

                    } else {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                        dialogText.setText("Oops, you missed that!!");
                    }


                    nextQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            {

                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }

        });

        mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                }

                if (mQuestionNumber > 9) {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(QuizQuestions.this, Results.class);
                    newIntent.putExtra("FINALSCORE", mScore);
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizQuestions.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.questions_dialog, null);

                    mBuilder.setView(mView);

                    dialogImg = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image);
                    dialogText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    nextQues = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.next_question);


                    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

                    if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
                        dialogText.setText("Well Done!!");

                    } else {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                        dialogText.setText("Oops, you missed that!!");
                    }


                    nextQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            {

                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }

        });

        mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                }
                if (mQuestionNumber > 9) {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(QuizQuestions.this, Results.class);
                    newIntent.putExtra("FINALSCORE", mScore);
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizQuestions.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.questions_dialog, null);

                    mBuilder.setView(mView);

                    dialogImg = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image);
                    dialogText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    nextQues = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.next_question);


                    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

                    if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
                        dialogText.setText("Well Done!!");

                    } else {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                        dialogText.setText("Oops, you missed that!!");
                    }


                    nextQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            {

                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }

        });

        mButtonChoice4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mButtonChoice4.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                }
                if (mQuestionNumber > 9) {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(QuizQuestions.this, Results.class);
                    newIntent.putExtra("FINALSCORE", mScore);
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizQuestions.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.questions_dialog, null);

                    mBuilder.setView(mView);

                    dialogImg = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image);
                    dialogText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                    nextQues = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.next_question);


                    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

                    if (mButtonChoice4.getText() == mAnswer) {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
                        dialogText.setText("Well Done!!");

                    } else {

                        dialogImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                        dialogText.setText("Oops, you missed that!!");
                    }


                    nextQues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            {

                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }

        });

        }



    private void updateQuestion(){
        mQuestionView.setText(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getQuestion());
        mButtonChoice1.setText(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getOptionOne());
        mButtonChoice2.setText(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getOptionTwo());
        mButtonChoice3.setText(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getOptionThree());
        mButtonChoice4.setText(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getOptionFour());
        img.setImageResource(questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getImage());

        mAnswer = questionArray[mQuestionNumber].getCorrectAnswer();
        mQuestionNumber++;

    }

    Question q01 = new Question("Which animal is considered the only flying mammal?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Flying Squirrel","Penguin","Bat","None of the above", "Bat");
    Question q02 = new Question("Which animal lay its eggs in the water?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Lion","Giraffe","Elephant","Frog", "Frog");
    Question q03 = new Question("Which animal have very long neck?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Beer","Giraffe","Leopard","Elephant", "Giraffe");
    Question q04 = new Question("How does Frogs catch their food?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Mouth","Hands","Tongue","None of the above", "Tongue");
    Question q05 = new Question("Where did Pandas originate from?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Egypt","Australia","South Korea","China", "China");
    Question q06 = new Question("What does Rhinoceros eat?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Meat","Plants","Meat and Plants","None of the above", "Plants");
    Question q07 = new Question("How does a Kangaroo move around?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Walking","Jumping","Running","All of the above", "Jumping");
    Question q08 = new Question("Within how long can baby Goats stand and take their first steps?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Minutes","Days","Weeks","Months", "Minutes");
    Question q09 = new Question("Do male Gorillas often have the same body size of the females?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Yes, they do","No, females often have bigger body","No, males often have bigger bodies","All of the above", "No, males often have bigger bodies");
    Question q10 = new Question("DE_R is missing one letter. What is it?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "A","E","I","R", "E");
    Question q11 = new Question("What happens when giant stars explode at the end of their lifecycle?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Small stars are formed","Disappears","Forms a Black Hole","None of the above", "Forms a Black Hole");
    Question q12 = new Question("How long does it take for sun light to reach the earth?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "2 minutes","6 minutes","8 minutes","10 minutes", "8 minutes");
    Question q13 = new Question("What is the name of the fourth planet from the sun?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Earth","Mars","Jupiter","Saturn", "Mars");
    Question q14 = new Question("How do dolphins breathe?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Through their nose","Through their blow hole","Using their gills","None of the above", "Through their blow hole");
    Question q15 = new Question("What is the name of the following fruit?", R.drawable.pomegranate_big_pic, "Pear","Pineapple","Pomegranate","Pumpkin", "Pomegranate");
    Question q16 = new Question("What is the name of the following animal?", R.drawable.lion_big_pic, "Tiger","Leopard","Snake","Lion", "Lion");
    Question q17 = new Question("What is the correct spelling of the following animal?", R.drawable.kangaroo_big_pic, "Kangaroo","Kangroo","Kangeroo","Kangaro", "Kangaroo");
    Question q18 = new Question("What is the world's largest land animal?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Whale","Elephant","Snake","Bear", "Elephant");
    Question q19 = new Question("What is the name of the following animal?", R.drawable.zebra_big_pic, "Horse","Donkey","Zebra","None of the above", "Zebra");
    Question q20 = new Question("What is the correct spelling of the following animal?", R.drawable.rhino_big_pic, "Rhinoseros","Rhinocros","Rhinoceros","Rhinosers", "Rhinoceros");
    Question q21 = new Question("What Panda's mostly eat?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Meat","Fish","Plants","Bamboo", "Bamboo");
    Question q22 = new Question("How many planets are there our solar system?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "9","7","8","6", "8");
    Question q23 = new Question("How many moons does Mercury have", R.drawable.ques_mark, "2","None","1","3", "None");
    Question q24 = new Question("What is the fourth largest planet in our solar system?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Venus","Uranus","Neptune","Saturn", "Neptune");
    Question q25 = new Question("What is the farthest planet from the sun?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "Jupiter","Neptune","Mercury","Saturn", "Neptune");
    Question q26 = new Question("Cantaloupes are good source of which vitamins?", R.drawable.cantaloupe_big_pic, "Vitamins A & B","Vitamins A & C","Vitamins B & C","Vitamins E & C", "Vitamins A & C");
    Question q27 = new Question("What is the name of the following fruit?", R.drawable.tangerine_big_pic, "Orange","Lemon","Peach","Tangerine", "Tangerine");
    Question q28 = new Question("How many limbs does and octopus has?", R.drawable.ques_mark, "7","10","8","6", "8");
    Question q29 = new Question("Where were onions first cultivated?", R.drawable.redonion_big_pic, "Japan","South Korea","China","Vietnam", "China");
    Question q30 = new Question("What is the correct spelling of the following animal?", R.drawable.squirrel_big_pic, "Squirel","Squirrel","Squirl","Squerril", "Squirrel");

    Question [] questionArray = new Question[]{
            q01, q02, q03, q04, q05, q06, q07, q08, q09, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, q19, q20, q21, q22, q23, q24, q25, q26, q27, q28, q29, q30
    };


    private void updateScore(int point) {
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);
    }

    public void shuffleQuestions(){
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(questionArray));
    }

}
```